# Duplicate error after inserting rows in table which fields has INDEXED(DUPLICATES OK)

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Here is my table. Two indexed columns with Indexed property set to Yes `(Duplicates OK)`
[image: My table]

Just like that:
[image: DUPLICATES OK!!!!]

But when I'm trying to insert rows using this code in `c# winforms`, as follows:

```cs
string query = "INSERT INTO Complaints(SickLeaveId, ComplaintId) " +
                "VALUES(14, 4)";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I get the following:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.'

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have just one index on this table? Check all the indexes if there are more than one. Also the duplicate index is on both columns?

Comment: @Steve i have two index on table and their indexed property set to Yes (Duplicates OK)

Comment: @Steve but when i insert these values in access i dont get any errors

Comment: Something weird then. What is your connectionstring? I have to ask. Are you sure that you are looking at the same database?

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your time, i just set both columns to not primary key and all worked. Thank you! Maybe you want to post ur comment as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried to create a table like yours and I have set the two columns with two NON UNIQUE indexes. One on the first column and one on the second column.

**No other indexes or primary key defined**. In this context your code has no problem in inserting many identical records. So the problem is somewhere else in the definition of your table

I suppose that you have a primary key defined on the table. 
This automatically create an unique index and thus you cannot insert duplicates in that column or in the columns set that define the primary key

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception You violate index or primary key of the table 
So Try to Generate Creation script of the table to ensure of all constrains on the table.

Comment: how can i generate creation script of the table in ms access?

Comment: also, when i insert rows with the same values in access i dont get any errors

Comment: As I see in table design image you shared table columns (SickLeaveId, ComplaintId) are primary key so you can't insert duplicated values you can overcome this issue by creating identity auto increment primery key

Comment: @Rintales you check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209505(v=office.12).aspx) it might help